# shifting summation index

Tags: summation

How would one shift the summation index to combine like terms in this expression?
I am finding this concept very confusing for some reason.

$\phi_{h}(z-z') + \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}[W^{n+1}_{TS}\phi_{h}(z+z'-2(n+1)h) + W^{n}_{TS}\phi_{h}(z+ z'+2(n+1)h)] + \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}W^n_{TS}[\phi_{h}(z-z'+2nh) + \phi_{h}(z-z'-2nh)].$

Comment: Could you just add and subtract the term for n=0 in the second summation; then combine the whole thing together?

Comment: Or you can use $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n+1)$, which is valid for any function $f$. This seems particulary suited to your equation.

Comment: @TonyK would that that still work though given the first term in the first summation has an additional $W_{TS}$ coefficient?

Comment: As I said, my substitution is valid for any function $f$. Obviously. So you can use it to rephrase the second summation; the first summation can stay as it is. You are left with a single summation, with three terms.